# Error: Unrecognized type: "Duration" (18)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I am trying to do a formula to minus the end date to the start date and then add it to the dataframe.

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit.components.v1 import iframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import base64
from datetime import time, datetime 
from io import BytesIO
import io

file_upload = st.file_uploader('Upload file','.xlsx')

if file_upload is not None:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_upload)
   
    #ASP
    asp = list(df["Installation_ASP"].drop_duplicates())              
    asp_choice = st.sidebar.multiselect('Choose ASP:', asp, default=None)
    df = df[df['Installation_ASP'].isin(asp_choice)]
    
     
    
    Installation_Duration = df['Installation_Actual_End'] - df ['Installation_Actual_Start']
    df['Installation_Duration'] = df['Installation_Actual_End'] - df ['Installation_Actual_Start']
    

    df = df[['Candidate_Site_ID','Installation_ASP','Installation_Actual_End','Integration_Actual','RA_Team_Approval_Date_Actual','Installation_Duration']]

    st.dataframe(df.reset_index(drop=True))
        
else:
    st.info('☝️ Please select a file to generate report')
```

but getting error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVEZT.png)

Comment: Can you provide a minimum content or demo of the uploaded file?

Comment: Which line creates the error?
If it's 18 (df = df[df['Installation_ASP'].isin(asp_choice)]), it all depends on your input.